# Restkit will not insert object attributes to path pattern for request URL path

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to run a find by ID request on a REST API. I'm using RestKit 0.20. I have a Location object. It has an id attribute. I want to make a GET request to '/locations/:id' and receive the complete object as JSON.
I have the backend and it's working. I'm now trying to write the iOS client code.

Here's what I have:

```
RKObjectManager* m = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

RKObjectMapping* lmap = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[lmap addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"id"]];
RKRequestDescriptor* req = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:lmap objectClass:[Location class] rootKeyPath:nil];
[m addRequestDescriptor:req];

Location* l = [[Location alloc] init];
l.id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:177];
[m getObject:l path:@"locations/:id" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"LOADED: %@", [mappingResult firstObject]);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"FAILED");
}];
```

After the code above is ran Restkit does not replace ':id: from the path with the ID attribute set in the Location object.

Do you guys have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I had both request and response descriptors set for the Location class. I had a route added for the find_by_id request but it was a Named Route, not a Class Route. When I used the getObject:path:parameters:success:failure method the router did not fill in the 'id' placeholder (irregardless whether it was named 'id', 'object_id', 'identity' or whatever).

The solution I found is this:

1. Continue using a Named Route but use the getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:object:parameters:success:failure method instead
2. User a Class Route and continue using the getObject:path:parameters:success:failure method

The problem I was having was that when using a NamedRoute like so:

```
RKRoute * route = [RKRoute routeWithClass:className pathPattern:path method:RKRequestMethodFromString(method)];
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:route];
```

and then querying for objects using the getObject:path:parameters:success:failure method did not cause the router to fill out any placeholders in the URL path.

Comment: 'id' is an Objective-C keyword. Don't call attributes by keywords. Change the attribute, mapping and key path to use 'identity'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm not getting any errors or warnings though when using 'id'. That doesn't make sense. The other parts of the code are correct, then?

Comment: Indeed it doesn't make sense. The code looks ok, though I haven't tried running it. What does the log output say?

Comment: Here's the relevant part of the log output: `restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:152 GET 'https://api.dev/v1/locations/:id'`. The only thing is that it doesn't replace the 'id' part. I'll try your suggestion and post the result.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and renamed the 'id' attribute to 'objid'. That didn't help - it was not replaced with the real objid of the location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a request descriptor, but your aren't making a 'request' (PUT / POST). When doing a GET you need to use a response descriptor. Also, the mapping you're creating isn't specifying the class (so it's linked against `NSDictionary`. I'd usually use the response descriptor with a router too. Something like:

```
RKObjectManager* m = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

RKObjectMapping* lmap = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Location class]];
[lmap addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"identity"]];

RKResponseDescriptor* req = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:lmap pathPattern:@"locations/:identity" keyPath:nil statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
[m addResponseDescriptor:req];

[m.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Location class] pathPattern:@"locations/:identity" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];

Location* l = [[Location alloc] init];
l.identity = [NSNumber numberWithInt:177];

[m getObject:l path:nil parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"LOADED: %@", [mappingResult array]);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"FAILED");
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I found the problem - see the update in my original post. I'll accept your solution as it seems to be free of the problem I was having. Also, I should note that everything is working now even with 'id' as the attribute name.